# How to connect subdomain in cPanel to AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, cpanel, amazon-elb

This is the situation:

1. I have a subdomain (i.e sub.domain.com) which has a cPanel and the domain namerserver must not be changed at all.
2. I have a classic load balancer in AWS with ec2 instances inside it that is already set up with Amazon Certificate Manager for its SSL Cert (cert DNS validated and in use).
3. Currently I added an A record in the subdomain that refer to IP address of one of the EC2 Instance, the problem is the EC2 does not come with the SSL Cert therefore could not access the site with https:// and I could not find anywhere on how to refer this subdomain to my load balancer with the cert so that the site can be opened with https://

Have tried various combinations in the subdomain record, A record also only allow IPv4 address while the ELB DNS is not.

Does anyone know how to connect my subdomain to my ELB? Thanks a lot in advance

[image: cPanel record]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same question. did you solve it?

Comment: not yet may possibly configure from the WHM, but unfortunately I have no access to the WHM, you may try it though.

Answer (score 0):

Your certificate (AWS Certificate Manager) is probably set to ONLY for the primary domain (domain.com), to fix this your certificate needs to slow down the subdomains as well, so I recommend creating a certificate for * .domain.com

After creating the certificate you will still have to bind it to Elastic Load Balancing.

More information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en/acm/latest/userguide/acm-certificate.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a type CNAME record instead of an A record in the Zone Editor of your cpanel. The load balancer DNS link inside the record input.

| Name | TTL | Class | Type | Record |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sub.domain.com. | 14400 | IN | CNAME | asdferiservdfer.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com. |

*PS* Don't create the subdomain beforehand. It won't work.